# How to track a click event on a line chart in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I click on a line in a line chart, I need to get the index of the corresponding data set. All examples allow you to track only the clicking of points, but the user can also click on a line. How to achieve this?
I'm using ChartJS 4

I tried to use [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition) but this option only tracks clicks on a dot or bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is probably no such thing in the API we will handle the `click` event ourselves. As you can see in code ChartJS provides methods to get the coordinates of mouse click position, and position of all datapoints in all datasets. In pixels all of those, right?

So equipped with all the points (in order), we can find the nearest series. This by checking the distance to each line segment in each series. The formula for distance between a point and a line is well known in analytical geometry so I took an implementation of a function `distanceToLine` I found online.

```js
// this function finds the nearest dataset to the mouse click
function handleClick(ev) {
  const canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(ev, myChart);
  const mx = canvasPosition.x
  const my = canvasPosition.y

  var min_distance = Infinity
  var winner = null

  for (j = 0; j < myChart.data.datasets.length; j++) {
  
    var meta = myChart.getDatasetMeta(j);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < meta.data.length - 1; i++) {
      var x1 = meta.data[i].x
      var y1 = meta.data[i].y
      var x2 = meta.data[i + 1].x
      var y2 = meta.data[i + 1].y

      var distance = distanceToLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, mx, my)
      
      if (distance < min_distance) {
        min_distance = distance
        winner = j
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  console.log("closest dataset: " + winner)
  return winner
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

const data = {
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
  datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 3
    },
    {
      label: '# of Something',
      data: [2, 13, 4, 15, 12, 6],
      borderWidth: 3
    }
  ]
}

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    },
    onClick: handleClick,
  }
})


//from: claude.ai
function distanceToLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, mx, my) {
  const dx = x2 - x1;
  const dy = y2 - y1;
  const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  if (length === 0) {
    // The line segment has zero length, so the distance is the distance from (mx, my) to (x1, y1)
    return Math.sqrt((x1 - mx) ** 2 + (y1 - my) ** 2);
  }

  const t = ((mx - x1) * dx + (my - y1) * dy) / (length * length);

  if (t < 0) {
    // The closest point is (x1, y1)
    return Math.sqrt((x1 - mx) ** 2 + (y1 - my) ** 2);
  } else if (t > 1) {
    // The closest point is (x2, y2)
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - mx) ** 2 + (y2 - my) ** 2);
  } else {
    // The closest point is the perpendicular projection of (mx, my) onto the line segment
    const projX = x1 + t * dx;
    const projY = y1 + t * dy;
    return Math.sqrt((projX - mx) ** 2 + (projY - my) ** 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```